# Springboot TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer KeepAliveTimeout not working

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have set the keep alive timeout in spring boot embeded tomcat server to 30 seconds. So i use below in the Application.java,

```
@Bean   
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    containerFactory
            .addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
                @Override
                public void customize(Connector connector) {
                    ((AbstractProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler())
                            .setKeepAliveTimeout(30000);
                }
            });

    return containerFactory;
}
```

Then i sleep a request thread for 40 seconds from my rest controller. But when i make a request via postman it successfully return HTTP status code 200 instead it should return gateway timeout error.

I try both setConnectionTimeout and setKeepAliveTimeout and it did not work.

What am i missing here?

**Edit question: My initial problem**

Let me explain the original question of mine, which lead me to ask above question.

**Well i have a long poll process which normally runs about more than 5 minits.**

So what happen is when i call the Rest API for longpoll, After 2.2 minits i get a 504 http error in browser.

I am using a AWS environment, where i have a ELB and a HAProxy which is installed in AWS EC2 instance.

As per AWS doc, it says **the default Idle Connection Timeout of ELB is 60 seconds**. So i have increase it to up to 30 mins.

Moreover it says,

> If you use HTTP and HTTPS listeners, we recommend that you enable the
>   keep-alive option for your EC2 instances. **You can enable keep-alive in
>   your web server settings** or in the kernel settings for your EC2
>   instances.

So have increase the embedded tomcat keep-alive timeout like above code snippet to 30.2 mins

So now i expect my long poll request to be completed, with out getting a 504 error. But still i get 504 error in browser?

Ref: [AWS dev guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/config-idle-timeout.html)

Comment: Try increase request timeout on client side.

Comment: through jQuery for example: `$.ajax({
    url: address.com/path,
    timeout: 40000,
    success: function(args) {  }
})`

Comment: thanks. well how this can override the server timeout? i mean if server not support a request to be live for instance 1 minit, then how can this work

Comment: Your approach correct, but i think client himself abort connection.

Comment: @Harshana, I don't think I understand your question or what you are trying to do.  The connection timeout is for idle connections so your server will never timeout and return a response on an active request.  You would have to have something in your controller to timeout if you have other processes behind there.  On the client side you would need a setting per application if you want to do it that way.  For postman I found this page https://www.getpostman.com/docs/settings.  What is your end goal?

Comment: ok lets say keep alive time out. If i set keep alive time out in tomcat for 30 seconds, and suppose a request takes to complete 40 seconds, then by 30 seconds i should get a http 504 error in browser right?

Comment: From the [Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation): **keepAliveTimeout**: 
The number of milliseconds this Connector will wait for another HTTP request before closing the connection. The default value is to use the value that has been set for the connectionTimeout attribute. Use a value of -1 to indicate no (i.e. infinite) timeout.

Comment: @ Nándor Előd Fekete How can i say tomcat to wait until x seconds while request (ex: longpoll) in being process

Comment: You linked to AWS guide that details load balancer configuration. It sounds like you are having problems with LB configuration, not with Tomcat configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you want to close abandoned HTTP connections which might occur on mobile devices.

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        containerFactory
                .addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
                    @Override
                    public void customize(Connector connector) {
                        ((AbstractProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setConnectionTimeout(100);
                    }
                });

        return containerFactory;
    }

    @RequestMapping
    public String echo(@RequestBody String body) {
        return body;
    }
}
```

Connection timeout has been set to 100 millisencods in order to run my tests fast. Data is sent in [chunks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). Between every chunk the running thread is suspended for x milliseconds.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = DemoApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest("server.port:19000")
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    private static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 1;
    private static final String HOST = "http://localhost:19000/echo";

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void slowConnection() throws Exception {
        final HttpURLConnection connection = openChunkedConnection();
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

        writeAndWait(500, out, "chunk1");
        writeAndWait(1, out, "chunk2");

        out.close();

        expectedException.expect(IOException.class);
        expectedException.expectMessage("Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: " + HOST);

        assertResponse("chunk1chunk2=", connection);
    }

    @Test
    public void fastConnection() throws Exception {
        final HttpURLConnection connection = openChunkedConnection();
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

        writeAndWait(1, out, "chunk1");
        writeAndWait(1, out, "chunk2");

        out.close();

        assertResponse("chunk1chunk2=", connection);
    }

    private void assertResponse(String expected, HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A");
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, scanner.next());
    }

    private void writeAndWait(int millis, OutputStreamWriter out, String body) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        out.write(body);
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    }

    private HttpURLConnection openChunkedConnection() throws IOException {
        final URL url = new URL(HOST);
        final HttpURLConnection  connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(CHUNK_SIZE);
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Set log level for package `org.apache.catalina.core` to `DEBUG`

```
logging.level.org.apache.catalina.core=DEBUG
```

and you can see a `SocketTimeoutException` for `slowConnection` test.

I don't know why you want HTTP status code 502 as error response status. [HTTP 502](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.3) says:

> The 502 (Bad Gateway) status code indicates that the server, while
> acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from an
> inbound server it accessed while attempting to fulfill the request.

The client `Postman` calls your server application. I don't see any gateway or proxy in between.

If you just condensed your question to a bare minimum and in reality you want to build a proxy on your own, you might consider using [Netflix Zuul](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki).

---

**Update 23.03.2016:**

That is the root cause for OP's question on Stackoverflow:

> What i did with longpolling was, from service api, i sleep the thread for some time and wake it and do it again and again untill some db status is completed.

That implementation actually prevents the Tomcat worker thread from processing new HTTP requests. As a result your request throughput reduces with every additional long running operation.

I propose to offload the long running operation into a separate thread. The client (browser) initiates a new request to fetch the result.
Depending on the processing status, server returns either the result or a notification/error/warning/.

Here's a very simple example :

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.CREATED;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.OK;

@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    private Map<String, String> results = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @RequestMapping(path = "put/{key}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> put(@PathVariable String key) {
        executorService.submit(() -> {
            try {
                //simulate a long running process
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                results.put(key, "success");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                results.put(key, "error " + e.getMessage());
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "get/{key}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> get(@PathVariable String key) {
        final String result = results.get(key);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, result == null ? NOT_FOUND : OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer and your answer was helpfull me to gain a new knowledge. But i still have doubts with my problem. I think the manner i asked the question misleaded you. So i have add my original problem in Edit question. Pls hav a look of it

Comment: Yes, your question was misleading for me. Documentation may sometimes be outdated. I would increase keep-alive to 10 minutes for Tomcat and web server and see what happens first.

Comment: well i had increase both ELB and tomcat (as shown in code) for 30 mins but still get the 503 in 2.2 mins. By the way when you say tomcat and web server, you refer the same right? Because springboot embeded tomcat is the web server here.

Comment: Yes, I meant web server == embedded Tomcat. The question is whether there is an additional web server in between your browser and server. BTW: I don't think it is a good idea to have a ordinary HTTP connection open for about 30 minutes. You should consider switching to polling or websockets.

Comment: Apparently I have to set timeout values of HAProxy also. Btw have you use HAProxy? If not what do you use as your load balancer?

Comment: Apparently it's working? That is what I meant with there might be an additional web server or proxy in between your browser and Tomcat. In short, a polling implementation off loads the work into a separate thread. Than you are calling periodically a separate URL which returns either the result or e.g. 404. Are you still interested in that solution?

Comment: exacly..just after you said that, the additional webserver came to my mind. I am intersted about your polling solution too. Kindly elaborate. What i did with longpolling was, from service api, i sleep the thread for some time and wake it and do it again and again untill some db status is completed. Is it a right way?