# EmbeddedTomcat and startStopThreads attribute

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

I've been looking all around and cannot find any good explanations or examples of using Spring 4.x (Springboot) with an EmbdeddedTomcat container and manually setting the `startStopThreads` attribute described [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/host.html)

I've noticed our application's startup latency has been getting worse over time, but also see (in the logs) the thread pool labeled `[localhost-startStop-1]` is the only thread ever executing beyond `[main]`.  I would like to add more threads into this pool to speed up our asynch startup.

Can anybody help me with Tomcat's `startStopThreads` issue?



**UPDATE -**
A good usecase for this is dynamically creating DynamoDb tables upon startup.  The creation code is wrapped in an `Executor.submit` call, however the logs show these being executed serially. Here's an example of whats in the logs:

```
2017-02-22 15:000:000:01,000 [main                 ] INFO Creating table 1 
2017-02-22 15:000:000:05,000 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO Creating table 2
2017-02-22 15:000:000:10,000 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO Creating table 3
```

Unfortunately, I am never seeing `localhost-startStop-2` execute anything, which it should if it were in the threadpool

Comment: I think maybe you need to create a `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` bean, as in the answer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461444/how-do-i-configure-this-property-with-spring-boot-and-an-embedded-tomcat). There are various `server.tomcat` variables that can be set in your `application.properties` described in the [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html), but I can't see `startStopThreads`.

Comment: I have my own `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` and I tried setting the `server.tomcat.maxThreads` and `server.tomcat.spareThreads` properties however it did not help.

I was even able to find the `Host` object and add a value for it's `setStartStopThreads` attribute, however that did not help either.

Comment: besides the config tips, what was your test case? did you invoke parallel requests properly?

Comment: @AntJavaDev - I've updated my original question with the use case information

Comment: cant see any post with your code / use case , only that you are calling an executor (!?!). Are you sure you invoking him properly , or are you using a : `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Configuring `startStopThreads` won't have any effect. It's used by each container in Tomcat (Service, Host, Context, etc) when starting their children. With more than one thread available a container with multiple children will start them in parallel. It won't have any effect in a typical Spring Boot application as each Tomcat container only has a single child.

Rather than trying to use Tomcat's threads to perform some initialisation in parallel, I'd recommend using a Java `Executor` or [Spring Framework's `TaskExecutor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-task-executor).

Comment: I've used `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` and `submit`ed callable tasks, however it's only running within the `local-startStop-1` thread and ONLY that thread

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't really tell me anything and it's really a separate question/problem to understanding what startStopThreads does. How many threads did you specify and what ThreadFactory did you pass in? I think a new question showing your code that's using the executor would be appropriate here.