# 504 Gateway Time-out issue in Spring Boot Rest call for heavy record(more than 80K)

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I am getting 504 Gateway Time-out issue Spring Boot Rest call using HTTP GET call for heavy record(more than 80K), I am calling other service to get data using RestTemplate object resClient, code as below:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> getData(String endPointUrl, Map<String, Object> parameterMap, String smToken) throws Exception {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.add("Cookie", smToken);
        //headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
        HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>> entity = new HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>>(parameterMap, headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = null;
        try {
            SSLUtil.turnOffSslChecking();
            LOGGER.info("Start call to end point : " +endPointUrl+ " at :"+ (new Date().toString()) );
            //resClient.getMessageConverters()
            //.add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            responseEntity = resClient.exchange(endPointUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity,String.class);
            LOGGER.info("End of call to end point : " +endPointUrl+ " at :"+ (new Date().toString()) );
            LOGGER.debug("Response from end point: " + responseEntity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception while making a http call to " + endPointUrl,e);
            throw e;
        }

        return responseEntity;
    }
```

While debugging I am seeing Response from other service call It takes more than 4 minutes, but rather than waiting it by that time to get response it use to come out only after 3 minutes. How can we make it to wait for response coming from other service call?

I tried to resolve this issue with increasing timeout time to 5 minutes using attribute server.connection-timeout=300000 in application.properties, but I am getting empty response. I am not sure If this is right approach or not. Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 11):

504 Gateway Time-out issue is generally thrown by proxy server that means server is closing connection.  If client close connection then you will get Connectiontimeout error.

Comment: Good tips. My haproxy configuration has 125s timeout.

Comment: Great tip. Actually, in my case,  the culprit was AWS load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) 
    {
        return restTemplateBuilder
           .setConnectTimeout(...)
           .setReadTimeout(...)
           .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`server.connection-timeout= #`

> Time that connectors wait for another HTTP request before closing the
>   connection. When not set, the connector's container-specific default
>   is used.

```
Use a value of -1 to indicate no (that is, an infinite) timeout. (might be bad fix)
```

---

OR Try to set it from Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("server.port","8080"));
        System.setProperty("server.connection-timeout","300000");
        System.setProperty("server.tomcat.max-threads","yourValue"); //in-case if you want to chaneg number of thredas 
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Also, Refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51066238/spring-server-connection-timeout-not-working)